# invalid type argument of unary '*' (have 'double') em C

Tags: c

nao entendi mt o porque desse problema estar acontecendo, ja fiz isso em outros programas e nunca tive problema, abaixo esta a funcao q esta dando o erro, se necessario posto todo o codigo.

```
    double Perimetro(Poligono P){
        Poligono A, B; 
        int i = 0;
        double *D; //armazena a distancia entre dois pontos
        double numvert, soma = 0;
        numvert = NumeroDeVertices(P);
        D = (double*)malloc(sizeof((double)*numvert));
        A = P;
        B = P->prox;
        for (i = 0; i < numvert; i++){
            D[i] = Distancia(A, B);
            A->prox = B;
            B = B->prox;
            soma = soma + D[i];
        }
        return soma;
    }
```

Comment: Creio que aqui: D = (double*)malloc(sizeof((double)*numvert)); deva ser: D = (double*) malloc(sizeof(double) * numvert);

Comment: Por que você está declarando o número de vértices como um `double`? Faz sentido ter 3.75 vértices? E por que você cria o vetor de distâncias, sendo que o seu problema é bem claro que não se faz necessário armazenar essa informação? E o que você esperava obter do tamanho de `(double)*numvert`? Ou você queria pegar o tamanho de `double` para só então multiplicar por `numvert`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Você esta multiplicando um double dentro do sizeof. o correto é: tamanho do tipo de dado * quantos espaços na memória você quer.

```
malloc(sizeof(double) * numvert);
```